# When i do npm install multer --save, i face the following error. I am not able to find the reason. I need some help in finding this issue

Tags: npm, save, installation, multer

this is the error! but I don't know why!

[image]

Comment: this is error message rongyuyingdeMacBook-Pro:tools rongyuying$ npm install multer --save

> magickwand@0.0.11 install /Users/rongyuying/sportq-platform-tools/webapps/tools/node_modules/magickwand
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: Wand-config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'Wand-config --cflags' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please update the question to post the code you have tried and the errors you have received - do not post the errors as a comment. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Please edit your image description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to install multer. It worked for me.

```
npm install @types/multer
```